# select checkboxes and send them as parameter to an action

Tags: javascript, ajax, symfony1, checkbox, checkboxlist

i'm trying to implement a massive delete action to a list of items, where every item has a checkbox, and there is a button to delete all the selected items. All that in symfony btw.

My biggest problem is: that list with the checkboxes comes from an AJAX call, so i can't define the listeners in the template where the list is defined. I need to do it in the template that recieves the AJAX response.

i give you some of my code:

- the template returning the list contains:

`

```
foreach($items as $item){
    echo '<input id="'.$item->getItemID().'" type="checkbox" onClick="[I CAN'T REFERENCE HERE A FUNCTION IN THE OTHER TEMPLATE]">';
    echo 'etc ...';
}`
```

- and the template recieving the list is

`

```
<div id="itemList">
    [the AJAX list goes here]  
</div>
<input type="button" value="delete all items">`
```

So my question is: How can i do it to implement that, when the button is pressed, call to for a symfony action with an array of selected checkboxes (or equivalent information) as parameter.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is get the array of checkboxes and pass them to the symfony. If you have the following `html`:

```
<input id="1" type="checkbox" class="delete">
<input id="2" type="checkbox" class="delete">
<input id="3" type="checkbox" class="delete">
<input id="4" type="checkbox" class="delete">
<input type="submit">
```

with the following `jquery`:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function(){
    var elems = new Array();
    $('.delete:checked').each(function(){
        elems.push($(this).attr('id'));
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'url',
        data: {elements_to_delete: elems}});
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/HbkvF/

Then you do a `executeDeleteBatch()` something like (not tested):

```
public function execute(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $ids = $request->getParameter('elements_to_delete');
  $count = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->delete()
    ->from('<YOUR CLASS>')
    ->whereIn('id', $ids)
    ->execute();
  }
}
```

`$count` returns the number of items deleted.